# prevent click inside js toggle to close down

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, toggle

I'm trying to stop the js toggle to close when clicking inside of it. I created a new function to stopPropagation for the class `keep_open` but this code is not even let me click on the button anymore. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php $finalres = "02-03";?>
<div>
  <h3>ページ<?php echo $finalres; ?><h3>
</div>
<div class="m_page2s" style="display:inline-block;clear: both;">
  <img src="<?php echo $my_column; ?>" width="950" height="225" "/> 
</div>
<div class="bgcontainer_center<?php echo $finalres; ?>">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="toggle<?php echo $finalres; ?>">
      <input type="button" value="<?php echo $finalres; ?>ページの写真を見る・変更">
      <div id="sidebar<?php echo $finalres; ?>">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var sidebarn = "#sidebar02-03";
        var number = "02-03";
        var sidebarVisible = localStorage.getItem('sidebar' + number) == 'true';
        $(sidebarn).toggle(sidebarVisible);
        $('.bgcontainer_center + number').toggleClass('clicked', sidebarVisible);
        $("#toggle02-03").click(function() {
            $(sidebarn).toggle("slow", function() {
                localStorage.setItem('sidebar' + number, $(sidebarn).is(':visible'));
            });
            $('.keep_open').click(function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                $(".bgcontainer_center + number").toggleClass('clicked');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: HTML is not complete, we can't tell what is a child , sibling, or parent. Out of the 6 divs, there are 4 that are not closed `</div>` It is important to have proper layout when interacting with DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are keeping the stopPropagation method inside another click event. Try separating out the events so that your code becomes like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sidebarn = "#sidebar02-03";
    var number = "02-03";
    var sidebarVisible = localStorage.getItem('sidebar' + number) == 'true';
    $(sidebarn).toggle(sidebarVisible);
    $('.bgcontainer_center + number').toggleClass('clicked', sidebarVisible);
    $("#toggle02-03").click(function() {
        $(sidebarn).toggle("slow", function() {
            localStorage.setItem('sidebar' + number, $(sidebarn).is(':visible'));
        });
    });
    $('.keep_open').click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(".bgcontainer_center + number").toggleClass('clicked');
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't believe I was missing the }); there, I was into that for about 1hour , I guess I was overlooking this code. Thank you very much, you help me a lot!